# pathfinding with multiple source and sinks?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding

I have a shortest path problem that I need to solve, and I'm fairly certain that there should be a efficient solution
I have this fun representation of a graph:

as ascii:

```
input

. N N N N N N
W 7 9 8 8 7 5 N . . . N N N
W 2 2 2 1 1 6 6 N N N 5 5 N E
W 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 4 5 5 4 2 5 E
. S S S 3 3 3 2 6 5 4 2 2 2 E
. . . . S S 2 2 2 2 3 7 2 2 E
. . . . . . S 2 3 2 7 7 7 7 E
. . . . . . . S 7 7 7 7 7 7 E
. . . . . . . S 7 7 7 S S 7 E
. . . . . . . . S 7 S . . S
. . . . . . . . . S

Output:
35
```

I need to find the shortest a path from one of the 'E' spots to one of the 'W' spots, walking over the numbered spots. We are not able to walk on the 'N' and 's' spots. When we stand at a spot, we´re able to walk up, down,left and right. I need to find the shortest path in terms of the numbered squares that I am walking on. Here is a more simple example:

[image]

I would create a double directed DAG with all edges going towards a numbered edge, having that number as weight, and all edges going to E or W having weight 0:

[image]

**my attempt**

Now this is a case of finding a shortest path from multiple sources to muliple sinks.
My naive thought is that I could run Dijkstra from every w, to every E. This would however run in something like O(W*dijkstra^E) (where E is the amount of E nodes)

Is there any smarter way to do a multi-source multi-sink dijsktra?

Comment: yes, all weights are positive, will make an attempt at converting the numbers

Comment: In your first diagram, the top-right N and E can't reach any numbered squares.

Comment: well in that the case of that E, then there is'nt any path from it to any W

Comment: Use a BFS with relaxation. Put all the W's into the queue. When you reach a node that hasn't been visited, assign it a weight, and add it to the queue. If a node has already been visited, check if the new path to the node has a lower weight. If so, update the weight, and add the node to the queue. When you reach an E, update its weight if improved, but don't add it to the queue. Continue until the queue is empty.

Comment: bfs with relaxation? is that bellman ford?

Comment: From wikipedia (emphasis added): *"Bellman–Ford algorithm is an algorithm that computes shortest paths from a **single source** vertex to all of the other vertices in a weighted **directed graph**"* So no.

Comment: In that case, im not really sure what you mean by bfs with relaxation. I don't really see how bfs could work on weighted graphs. Could you maybe provide a link?

Comment: I'm sure that other people have used this algorithm before me, but I don't know their names. So I'm afraid I can't tell you what to search for.

Comment: I think I have enough to go from, will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution was [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901010/pathfinding-with-multiple-source-and-sinks/64903380#comment114745417_64901010) but bears conversion to an answer: run a normal BFS but re-enqueue any previously visited nodes which can be reached with lower cost than previously thought. Re-enqueing a newly-discovered cheaper path to a visited node lets us recompute its neighbor paths as well.

The downside is that BFS will explore all nodes at least once, so the optimality depends on the type of graph you have--if it's a graph with many starting and ending points relative to the size of the graph as in your example, this is good, whereas running multiple Dijkstra's becomes appealing as the number of sources and sinks diminishes relative to the size of the graph.

Here's the code:

```js
const findAllCoords = (G, tgt) => 
  G.reduce((a, row, ri) => {
    const res = row.reduce((a, cell, ci) => 
      cell === tgt ? [...a, [ci, ri]] : a
    , []);
    return res.length ? [...a, ...res] : a;
  }, [])
;

const shortestPathMultiSrcMultiDst = (G, src, dst) => {
  const key = ([x, y]) => `${x} ${y}`;
  const dstCoords = findAllCoords(G, dst);
  const visited = Object.fromEntries(
    dstCoords.map(e => [key(e), Infinity])
  );
  const neighbors = ([x, y]) =>
    [[0, -1], [-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
    .map(([xx, yy]) => [x + xx, y + yy])
    .filter(([x, y]) => 
      G[y] && (!isNaN(G[y][x]) || G[y][x] === dst)
    )
  ;
  const q = findAllCoords(G, src).map(e => [e, 0]);
  
  while (q.length) {
    let [xy, cost] = q.shift();
    const [x, y] = xy;
    const k = key(xy);
    cost += isNaN(G[y][x]) ? 0 : +G[y][x];
    
    if (!(k in visited) || cost < visited[k]) {
      visited[k] = cost;
      q.push(...neighbors(xy).map(e => [e, cost]));
    }
  }

  return Math.min(...dstCoords.map(e => visited[key(e)]));
};

const G = `
. N N N N N N
W 7 9 8 8 7 5 N . . . N N N
W 2 2 2 1 1 6 6 N N N 5 5 N E
W 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 4 5 5 4 2 5 E 
. S S S 3 3 3 2 6 5 4 2 2 2 E
. . . . S S 2 2 2 2 3 7 2 2 E
. . . . . . S 2 3 2 7 7 7 7 E
. . . . . . . S 7 7 7 7 7 7 E
. . . . . . . S 7 7 7 S S 7 E
. . . . . . . . S 7 S . . S
. . . . . . . . . S
`.trim().split("\n").map(e => e.split(" "))
;
console.log(shortestPathMultiSrcMultiDst(G, "W", "E"));
```

---

OP [shared a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64937429/6243352) that simply turns the problem into a regular Dijkstra-solvable graph by connecting all sources to a node and all sinks to a node, rendering this solution pretty much pointless as far as I can tell.

Comment: which runtime would this problem have? O(Enodes*(V+E))?

Comment: since I could end up exploring every node Enodes times?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the time complexity which is why I didn't add it, but your analysis seems intuitively OK to me. [This paper](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall11/rec/rec15.pdf) seems to offer the best treatment I could find with a few minutes of searching but I didn't have time to dig in. I'll update if I can solidify my understanding and in the meantime feel free to edit or drop a comment if you come up with anything.

Comment: ggorlen, I have added my very own attempt at an answer, I would be very happy to have more people review it

Comment: Yeah, your solution looks much better. I think it totally solves the problem and is always more optimal than this, so feel free to move the checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

After giving this some thought, and I think I have come up with a solution myself. The accepted answer is completely valid and good, but I think should run faster than A bfs that in the worst case needs to evaluate each edge E times.

Here goes:
I connect all E nodes with a source, with edges going from the source (s) to E, with weight 0.
All W nodes are also connected to a sink (t), edges going from W to sink.

This means that the beforeshown graph will look like this:

[image]

Now I should be able just to run a regular ol' dijkstra from s to t

Comment: this is a much better answer than the currently-accepted one.

Comment: I agree--I came across this while poking around but somehow didn't think to apply it to this problem. Feel free to move the checkmark.

Comment: Great solution. Note that it's pretty much equivalent to initializing Dijkstra with _all_ source nodes instead of just one, and stopping as soon as it reaches _any_ sink node instead of _the_ one.